# Send email once to multiple recipients using django-post_office

Tags: django, email

I want to send a email to a group of user in django app.

I am using django post office as I will be sending email asynchronously.

So I got to know about the send many function of it but that also create separate email object for different recipient.

Is sending email using bcc field is possible with post_office.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After downloading and reviewing the source from GitHub, it does not look like [django-post_office](https://github.com/ui/django-post_office) supports bcc out of the box.  The good news is that the Email model (models.py) creates the email message using Django's EmailMultiAlternatives, which supports bcc.  So with some minor tweaking of the source on your part, it can be quickly supported.

Comment: Oh .. Thanks for the help. I will try your suggestion.